# iPhone/iOS with UIKeyboard + customized toolbar layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, uikeyboard

I have recently clone QuickDialog project from github and played around with it.

They seem to use the default iOS keyboard but with an extra customized view, i.e. the row that has "Previous" "Next" and "Done". Screenshot is as following 2 images:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Whereas the default `UIKeyboard` will not have that row regardless what the `UIKeyboardType` is.

I tried to look at the source code to see how they implemented that but with no luck. Does anyone know how they have done this kind of keyboard?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to take custom toolbar . and in viewdidload hide toolbar den on textfieldshouldbegin editing show toolbar and put custom uibuttons or toolbar buttons on toolbar. also set toolbar frame above the keyboard

Comment: Thanks Chinttu, I will see if this works and continue to find how they have done that.

Comment: i have done that dude ... it works for me ... so it will also work for you. u have to just take iboutlet of toolbar and button and set frame and show hide as per your need .

Comment: first just take outlet of toolbar den hide in viewdid load and on textfield shouldbeginediting show that .. dont take buttons. do that step by step so you'll know how it works.

Comment: i followed your comment and it works nicely! thanks for your help again! can i give u any credits on this?

Comment: ya u can upvote coments :) .... n e time buddy ... Happy Coding ...

Comment: sorry i am quite new to stackoverflow, how do i vote up a comment? i cannot see any buttons next to the comments. is it because i don't have enough reputation points?

Comment: k on left side of comment start just take pointer to there and you'll get upvote button . maybe yes your reputation is low so u cant get it ... no problem dude ... u got your answer thats it ... Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have to add toolbar on keyboard. Use key board Notification (KeyboardWillShow & KeyboardWillHide) for showing toolbar on keyboard. You can also refer below URL

https://github.com/SimonBS/BSKeyboardControls

https://github.com/wannabegeek/PickerTableViewCell

https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl

Comment: thanks! I looked at BSKeyboardControls source code and that is exactly what i want and it's quite easy to follow! So i will take your answer.